# How to architect a grid view directive that allows columns to be reordered / hidden?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pug

I am trying to create an AngularJS directive that looks something like this:

```
gridview(ng-show="people.length > 0")
    column(name="checkbox")
        th
        td
            input(type="checkbox" ...)
    column(name="name" moveable toggleable)
        th Name
        td
           input(type="text" ng-model="person.name")
    column(name="address" moveable toggleable)
        ...
    column(name="phone" moveable toggleable)
        ...
    column(name="actions")
        td
            a(href="#") delete

gridview-settings(ng-show="people.length > 0")
```

I'm wondering what is the best way to build this directive?

The `gridview-settings` should pop up a modal with the column names that I can check to enable/disable and also re-order.

How do I conditionally render a table in the correct order of columns?

How do I share the column information between `gridview` and `gridview-settings`?

P.S., I've already looked at several gridview libraries and none of them are suitable for what I'm trying to do so I'm looking for help to build this directive, not a reference to another library.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some research and experimenting and this is what I came up with.  Not sure it is the best way.  I am still open to other ideas.

```
directive: gridview
   compile:
     - parse the markup to extract the declarative table definition
   pre-link:
     - save the declarative definition in a scope variable (specified from an attr)
     - load any user preferences from backend
   post-link:
     - render the table
     - watch for changes to declarative definition from gridview-settings and re-render

directive: gridview-settings
   - receives the reference to the declarative specification as an attr (name of the var on the scope)
   - allows for changes to the declarative settings
```